# Does the 'PropertyChanged' event keep Views alive for the life of models that use it?

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Does the 'PropertyChanged' event keep Views alive for the life of models that use it?

For instance, does this code not keep the view alive for the life of the view model?

```
    public MyView(MyViewModel a_viewModel)
    {
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                DataContext = a_viewModel;
            };
    }
```

OK, bad example. Here is the code I'm actually worried about in my `ViewModelBase` class:

```
protected void RelayPropertyChanges(INotifyPropertyChanged a_source, String a_strSourceProperty, String a_strTargetProperty)
{
    ValidatePropertyExists(a_strTargetProperty);

    if (a_source is ViewModelBase)
       (a_source as ViewModelBase).ValidatePropertyExists(a_strSourceProperty);

    a_source.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(a_strTargetProperty);
}
```

And, I just realized that this won't work right.  I'll get back to you guys on this; any ideas on ways to make this work?

Comment: By alive do you mean not GC'ed?

Comment: Yup (But 'yup' is to short a comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "PropertyChanged" event is no different than any other event, so let's discuss events in general.

When an instance of your view (we'll call it `V`) subscribes to an event on the model (`M`), it hands a reference of itself to the model in the delegate.   So `M` now holds a reference to `V`.  If you continue to use `M` in other code, yes - that reference will keep the instance of `V` from being garbage collected.

You can remove this concern by "unsubscribing" to the event in the View, or making sure your model doesn't outlive it by too long (in which case it's probably just not a problem).  There are other approaches where people use "weak events" - but this requires some modification to your design and is not "built-in" to the framework or language (see articles like http://kutruff.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/high-performance-property-changed-weak-event-notifications-for-c/)

Since you ask about "PropertyChanged" specifically, you are probably worried about databinding (and you've tagged with WPF).  In this case the answer is "probably not".  The data binding manager is "smart" enough to weakly reference the view *if* you inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use Dependency Properties.  If not, and you are not using `OneTime` binding, then the view will not be collected when you think it should (see this KB for more info http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416 )

Comment: I am familliar with eventing, subscription, and the lot. My concern is around delegates (more specifically lambda expressions).  I'm trying to create a relaying system in my view models (in the base class) so that changes to the models can automatically be relayed to the view model and then to the view.  Every model I am using uses the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  I was wondering if the lambda expressions that I was storing to perform the relaying would keep the views alive by the models. I'll add the code to my question.